# Automating Backups using Event scheduler

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an automating backup using Event scheduler in MySQL.

Here is my script :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Backup` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK 
STARTS '2013-06-14 18:19:02' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
SET @sql_text = CONCAT ( "SELECT * FROM BonInterne INTO OUTFILE '/home/aimad/GestionStock/" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d') , "BonInterne.csv'" ); 
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text; 
EXECUTE s1; 
DROP PREPARE s1;
```

When I execute it I get an error in the line `PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NULL' at line 1

what is the problem with my script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple statements have to be put between `BEGIN` and `END`. Also you have to change the delimiter, or else MySQL thinks that the event creation statement is finished with the first `;`. And at last, it's `DEALLOCATE PREPARE ...`, not `DROP PREPARE...`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `Backup` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK 
STARTS '2013-06-14 18:19:02' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
BEGIN
SET @sql_text = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM BonInterne INTO OUTFILE '/home/aimad/GestionStock/" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d') , "BonInterne.csv'" ); 
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text; 
EXECUTE s1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```