# MySQL backup using event

Tags: mysql, backup

for my current project I need to create every week a backup of the whole datebase(incl. procedures, functions, triggers, etc.) by createing a dumpfile. I'm not experienced with events, so I thought someone could help me.

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115078/automating-backups-using-event-scheduler) post, but I need to save the whole db not only the inserts.

If you have other suggestions for a backup let me know :)

EDIT:
I'm using a Debian GNU Linux 8.x.

Comment: In Windows you can use Scheduled task to run backup.

Comment: @Devart i'm using a linux server, but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, I see) Have a look at this one (cron command) - https://debian-administration.org/article/56/Command_scheduling_with_cron