# Backup Whole Database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to backup my whole database.I have seen shell scripting.But is it possible to backup whole database using event scheduler.
I  have check the follwing link-
[Automating Backups using Event scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115078/automating-backups-using-event-scheduler)

It contains table backup not the database bavkup
Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "event scheduler"

Comment: where do you want to store the backup database? Same server or somewhere else?

Comment: @zerkms-event scheduer means mysql events for specific scheule

Comment: @Md.MahmudHasan-store backup on same server

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497869/export-and-import-all-mysql-databases-at-one-time

Comment: @FreudianSlip- These are shell scripts,i want an sql query or is it possible to use it in sql query?

Comment: Creating a consistent backup requires lot more than just some basic sql script. Is there any particular reason why you cannot use a proper backup solution and you want to create your own version? Btw using mysqldump is not shell scripting. It is just simply invoking  a program with the right parameters.

Comment: Agreed by is mysqldump be used in queries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating Backups using Event scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115078/automating-backups-using-event-scheduler)

Comment: @NicoHaase- that's not a duplicate because its table backup

Answer (score 0):

use mysqldump to take backup.
write a query to convert it into csv

```
  select * from table into outfile 'E:/path/' fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' ;
```

Comment: This is shell scripting .I want query for database backup

Comment: you want sql query?

Comment: if possible yes because i will use it in event